# flutter widget named "scrollable_positioned_list" how to judge it has scrolled to top?

Tags: flutter

I use flutter widget named "scrollable_positioned_list", but do not know how to judge it has scrolled to top?
I review the source code, and do not find a method or way to judge the listView has scrolled to top.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemPositionsListener.positions.addListener((positions) => ...);
```

you can monitor what is visible in the screen with this. not sure is this what you are asking.

Comment: Hi, the doc show this :itemPositionsListener.positions.addListener(() => ...); so, the question is still.